# excel proteger celdas

Tags: excel, contraseña

Estoy tratando de proteger con ***contraseña*** una ***columna*** de IDs en excel, ¿es posible hacer eso sin bloquear el resto de la hoja?

Gracias.

Comment: Que versión de excel tienes?

Answer (score 2):

Las celdas de Excel poseen una propiedad llamada "**Bloqueada**" de forma predefinida. 
Esta propiedad se encuentra pulsando **Click derecho** sobre la celda o celdas que queramos, en la opción "**Formato de celdas**" y la pestaña "**Proteger**". También podemos usar el atajo `CTRL + 1`.

Esta propiedad es la que debemos deshabilitar. Como tu buscas solamente dejar protegida una columna, tendrás que deshabilitar la propiedad "**Bloqueada**" de toda la hoja excepto de la columna que desees.

Esto lo puedes hacer quitando toda la propiedad a la hoja entero seleccionándola toda (o un área considerable que quieras) y volviendo a dar la propiedad "**Bloqueada**" a la columna que quieres.

Con esto hecho, solo queda proteger la hoja como lo harías en cualquier caso normal y tu columna será lo único protegido en toda la hoja.

Comment: así lo haré entonces. Gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: Si esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, por favor, márcala como correcta para cerrar la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Las celdas están bloqueadas por defecto, debes deshabilitar el bloqueo de las quiere seguir modificando
Click derecho-formato de celda-proteccion-bloqueado
A las q se lo deshabilites, aunque bloquees la hoja, las podrás modificar.

Comment: entendido. Gracias por tu respuesta!